# new SimpleXMLElement doesn't like colons

Tags: php, xml, php-5.6

My PHP code is

```
<?php
$envelopeXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<s:Envelope></s:Envelope>');
$envelopeXML->addAttribute('xmlns:s', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $envelopeXML->asXML();
```

And it gives me warning:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): namespace error : Namespace prefix s on Envelope is not defined in xml.php on line 2

How do I define namespace prefix 's' on 'Envelope'? Like this one:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue</a:Action>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the namespace directly in the XML variable itself as long as it follows valid XML rules:

```php
<?php
$envelopeXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"></s:Envelope>');
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $envelopeXML->asXML();
```